# Encrypt javascript file automatically before charge it in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how can i encrypt the javascript files before charge it in the browser?

I have a lot of javascript files i can't do the encryption manually so i need a way to do this automatically.

I just want the code to be unreadable.

Comment: You mean obfuscuation? If you want encryption - how do you plan to decrypt it on the client side?

Comment: @Strinder exactly, I just want the code to be unreadable

Comment: I believe it's called *minify*

Comment: _can i encrypt the javascript files before charge it in the browser_ Simply No. You can't. what you can do is minify only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said *encryption* won't work, since your user's browsers wouldn't know how to decrypt those files. *Minification* is possible (and advisable for various reasons), but you have to understand, that it's not possible to make JS code completely unreadable for the user. Minification can still be reverted to some extend.

Anyways there's multiple ways to minify your code, and the most popular one is to use a build system, such as [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp).

If neccessary, check their docs first on how to set up node.js and gulp's dependencies. Once that's done, you can use this simple Gulpfile to minify JS code in you current directory and subdirectories and store the results in a subfolder called `dist/`:

**gulpfile.js**:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('minify', () => {
  return gulp.src('**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});
```

Once that's done you upload those minified JS files to your server instead of the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at https://cloakedjs.com/ which supports minification, obfuscation, AES encryption, debug protection, and domain locking. The encrypted code is decrypted dynamically for execution so it can't be 100% secure, but it makes it harder for other to analyze or abuse. There is also an associated web service that will cloak files on the fly so they are different every time using polymorphic obfuscation.